# BizTalk 2009 Assembly Locations

Tags: biztalk, assemblies, biztalk-2009

When I deploy a schema to BizTalk where is it stored?

Comment: is it stored in the GAC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559668(BTS.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

In the global assembly cache (GAC)

Answer (score 0):

In the global assembly cache (GAC) --path as below

C:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly\GAC_MSIL